# Robot Framework - No keyword found - using IP address as TARGET

Tags: automation, robotframework

I am getting an 'No keyword with name....' error as seen below. I think it is something to do with my Test case referencing an IP address but not sure?

See my Test code and CLI output below, appreciate the help

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Suite - Open Connections and do a simple comparison test
Suite Setup     Device Open Connection      @{TARGET}
Suite Teardown  Device Close Connection     @{TARGET}
Library         OperatingSystem
Library         /Users/xxx/Desktop/CI/RobotTestingFramework/Libraries/pybot_jrouter.py    target=${TARGET}    WITH NAME    ${TARGET}
Library         /Users/xxx/Desktop/CI/RobotTestingFramework/Libraries/iplib.py
Resource        /Users/xxx/Desktop/CI/RobotTestingFramework/Resources/device_resources.robot
Resource        /Users/xxx/Desktop/CI/RobotTestingFramework/Resources/version_resources.robot

*** Variables ***
${USERNAME}    xxx
${PASSWORD}    Juniper123
${path}    ./Report
@{TARGET}    192.168.1.100
${OSversion}    12.1R1.9

*** Test Case ***
Check Software Version
    [Documentation]    Test - Version Check
    [Tags]    version
    FOR    ${target}    IN    @{TARGET}
    Check Software Version    ${target}    ${OSversion}
    END
```

Check Version Software -

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    /Users/xxx/Desktop/CI/RobotTestingFramework/Resources/device_resources.robot
Library     String
Library     Collections
Library     XML

*** Keywords ***
Check Software Version
    [ARGUMENTS]    ${device}    ${software-version}
    ${get-software-details}    Command Executor    ${device}    show version    xml    //junos-version
    Should Be Equal    ${software-version}    ${get-software-details}    The Junos OS version is different than expected!
```

Open Connection -

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   A resource file with reusable keywords for 'executing the command in device',initiate device connection and tear down device connection.It can be used for any devices such as  SWITCH,ROUTER,FIREWALL.     NOTE: It has to be developed further to make it complete generic


*** Keywords ***

Device Open Connection
    [Arguments]    @{devices}
    FOR    ${device}    IN    @{devices}
    Run Keyword    ${device}.Open Connection
    END






Check Version :: Suite - Open Connections and do a simple comparison test     
==============================================================================
Check Software Version :: Test - Version Check                        | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
No keyword with name '192.168.1.100.Open Connection' found.
```

Comment: Are all of those libraries really required to debug this? It would help if you could reduce this code down to a [mcve]. Nobody is going to be able to run this test because of all of the custom libraries and resources. We'll also need to see a definition of the `Check Software Version` keyword since it appears the error is coming from there.

Comment: Add the source of the `Device Open Connection` keyword, the failure is somewhere there.

Comment: I have added the Check Software Version & Open Connection - does this help? Admit, I am fairly new to this, but i am trying to follow an example of connecting to a Juniper router and checking the software version. Extra libraries are from Juniper.

Comment: It looks very suspicious that you are defining `@{target}` in the variables section, but then trying to use it as a scaler in an import statement. Why are you doing that? That may be part of the problem. Have  you tried changing `@{TARGET}    192.168.1.100` to `${TARGET}    192.168.1.100`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I can tell you why it throws the error, but it's up to you to change it so it's fixed - it's hard to deduct the intent w/o knowing the end goal, the libraries, etc.

The error states:

> Parent suite setup failed:
> No keyword with name '192.168.1.100.Open Connection' found.

Your suite setup - where the error came from - is `Device Open Connection      @{TARGET}`, e.g. calling the keyword with arguments the members of the list "TARGET" (e.g. an expanded list). That keyword is doing a loop over all arguments it was passed, and does:

```
Run Keyword    ${device}.Open Connection
```

, where "device" is the current loop's value.
The built-in `Run Keyword` does just that - it expects a keyword name & will execute it. So you are effectively passing "192.168.1.100.Open Connection", and expecting - what? :) The framework to execute such keyword? But you have not defined it, and - it's failing with that message.

This is the moment I (at least) cannot help further - that's the reason you are seeing *this* error message, but where to take it from here - :).
Perhaps, there's a method/keyword "Open Connection" somewhere in those libraries, that expects the IP address; I don't know, I'm just guessing from here on.

Comment: Hi Todor, first of all thanks for checking this out. I thought that may be an issue as examples i have followed include a hostname, not an IP. Excuse me, but is there somewhere I can define this IP address as a hostname within the Robot Framework, so that a hostname is passed to the Test instead of the IP address? Thanks in advance,

Comment: In anyways, if you pass a host name to `Run Keyword` the framework will try to execute a keyword that is named exactly like that - which I doubt will be possible. As of defining host name <-> ip mapping, depends on what you mean. If it's like a real DNS, or similar to hosts files, no, I don't think so - that's in the OS, not in an application like RobotFramework. If you just need a mapping, you can use a dictionary variable - the host is the key, the ip the value; or vice versa.